# Can't get eclipse to start after a computer crash

Tags: java, eclipse, virtual-machine

I am running eclipse in a virtual machine. The vm ran out of memory so it had to shut down. Now when I try to start eclipse, nothing happens. A process starts in the task manager but it hardly is holding any memory and no windows pop up, simply nothing happens. Here is the log file in .metadata

```
Log:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2013-09-05 14:49:58.989
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2013-09-05 14:50:14.848
!SESSION 2013-09-05 15:03:21.108 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

And now, whenever I try to start eclipse, nothing ever gets appended to the log. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that is a virtual machine.

- save your work in a pen drive or in the native OS (all .java files  and any useful library etc, those files are accessible also outside eclipse IDE)

After this there are two options:

- uninstall eclipse and re-install it.

or

- format your virtual hard drive and continue with a clean OS.

In any case your work is safe in your pen drive.

I had the same problem time ago, don't bother why is not working because I spent hours without results, don't waste your time. Reinstall or format.

Comment: I ended up just deleting the vm and reinstalling it so I'm back up and running. Probably saved a lot of time, thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome ;) I know what means lose so much time with this error lol, have a good programming